# Как связать файл где определен сервис или директива и файл контроллера

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Например есть файл service.js есть файл app.js

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
app.controller('MainCtrl', function(myService,$scope){
  $scope.value = myService.value;
});
```

service.js

```
app.factory('myService', function(){
      return{
       value: 1
       }
    });
```

Как физически связать эти файлы, что б из контроллера был виден сервис (так как в таком виде сервис из контроллера не доступен, выдает ошибку). Нужно ли использовать сборщики, или это делается как-то по другому "автоматически")) извините за детский вопрос. Спасибо!

Comment: Какая ошибка? Вы в service.js angular.module('myApp') Подключаете?

Comment: Если присутствует файл в котором **создается** модуль _myApp_, то в данном случае достаточно подключить в html `service.js` после `app.js` и все будет работать. Если такой файл отсутствует, то ошибка будет при выполнении app.js - о невозможности получить модуль.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, да, действительно в html не подключал, а это нормально все части js файлов подключать в html, можно ли сделать так что б в html подключался главный app.js , а всё остальное между собой биндилось без хардкода в <head></head>

Comment: @AlexeyAntonovich, с ангуляром - проблематично. Можно использовать различные сборщики, которые все соберут в один файл, но это не то же самое что подгружать файлы по запросу

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо использовать для этого [gulp](http://blog.angular-university.io/what-every-angular-project-likely-needs-and-a-gulp-build-to-provide-it/) или [webpack](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/26017-2)